# What kind of yellow is used for a typical minifigure?

Tags: minifigures, colour

I've done some research and found a basic LEGO basic [colour pallet](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Colour_Palette). I recognise the yellow used for yellow bricks (24, Bright Yellow, #fec400) but it doesn't seem to match the colour for minifigures which are slightly less orange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it is supposed to be 24 Bright Yellow, however I know there were some complaints a last year or so regarding the collectable Minifigures and others that were made in China not having the same hue as "regular" minifigures - and now that some of the licensed products are also being made there, this difference will become more common.

These figures are apparently not made from ABS but a cheaper plastic, which is what causes the difference in colour.