# Can you identify these (possibly) LEGO horses?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

We got these old LEGO-compatible horses from the LEGO collection that used to belong to my wife's brothers (which means they are probably 20-30 years old). I'm wondering if they are genuine LEGO pieces.

If not, I wonder what brand are they.

Either way, I wonder which set, if any, they belonged to.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think there was another black horse, which I couldn't find, and some or all of them also had a brown saddle part.

EDIT:

I managed to take a good photo of the stamp on the black horse, so it's definitely genuine LEGO.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those horses look like legit LEGO-brand horses.

Specifically:

**White Horse with Black Eyes, White Pupils and Dark Orange Bridle Pattern**: [4493c01pb04](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4493c01pb04)

[image: White horse]

**Black Horse with Black Eyes Circled with White, Brown Bridle Pattern**: [4493c01pb02](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4493c01pb02)

[image: Black horse]

In order to be extra sure they are genuine LEGO, look for the "LEGO" stamp on the inside of the hollow studs on their back where the saddle goes (it's a little hard to see).

These horses each came in a fair number of sets. Check the BrickLink links for a list of possible sets. If you are sure they both came in the same set, these are the sets both came in:

- [5394-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5394-1)
- [6021-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6021-1)
- [6042-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6042-1)
- [6055-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6055-1)
- [6073-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6073-1)
- [6074-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6074-1)
- [6080-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6080-1)
- [6081-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6081-1)
- [6085-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6085-1)
- [6086-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6086-1)
- [6090-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6090-1)
- [6095-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6095-1)
- [6419-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6419-1)
- [6761-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6761-1)
- [6762-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6762-1)
- [6769-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6769-1)
- [8777-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8777-1)
- [10039-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10039-1)
- [10176-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10176-1)

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, there is some stamp on the inside of the hollow studs. I didn't notice it earlier. It could be LEGO, though it's hard to read properly.

Comment: It was already identified, but just to mention, recently there was a set (10676) that contains the white horse. I can confirm because I have it. Also, when I was a kid I had a set that had the black horse (now lost because I was a dumb kid)

Comment: @Moacir: 10676 has a different white horse ([10352c01pb04](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=10352c01pb04)).

Comment: @kundor Oh, sorry. It is a similar piece but not the one OP asked for. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 9):

They are:

[LEGO Animal Minifigure - WHITE HORSE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002GPRM6C)

[image: LEGO Animal Minifigure - WHITE HORSE]

and

[Horse (Black) - LEGO Animal Minifigure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00409NPMC)

[image: LEGO Animal Figure Horse (Black)]

But if it does not have the logo or part ID then it must be a copycat.

Refer this post for real LEGO identification help:

[General guidelines to identify real Lego pieces from fake or copy?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10658/general-guidelines-to-identify-real-lego-pieces-from-fake-or-copy)

Answer (score 4):

Since you are asking for a set too,
I remember playing with this sort of horse long ago.

Mine was the horse of a knight, like in [this set](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/lego_instructions/set/6074/Black_Falcons_Fortress).

Answer (score 4):

I owned [these two](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/6086/Black_Knight's_Castle) [medieval castle sets](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/6085/Black_Monarchs_Castle) as a child. Both came with different coloured horses (white, brown and black).

There are also a number of knight sets containing horses, for example [this one](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/6021/Jousting_Knights).