# Is this part real LEGO or a knockoff?

Tags: piece-information, clone-brands

I bought a LEGO lot off craigslist a few days ago with some sets and some bulk parts. It included some parts that appeared to have been bought in bulk (maybe pick-a-brick?). It also had some random non-lego pieces as we all know is standard to find in these large bulk lots.

Amongst the bulk, I found around 40 of a 1x1x6 support pillar in dark blue color. The part seems somewhat rare and they go for around $5/ea on bricklink, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out if they are real LEGO.

Pictures of said part:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Evidence:

1. Top stud is hollow which Bricklink says is a normal variant of the
   part.
2. It looks the same as the 3D model of the hollow stud part on Bricklink.
3. There is no LEGO logo or part number anywhere that I can see.
4. There is a small seam that runs along the full length of the part on opposite sides.
5. There is a small number on the outside of the part on the bottom of the rounded section.
6. The part is the correct dark blue color when compared to other dark blue LEGO pieces.
7. The part feels like LEGO and has the new LEGO sheen.
8. I have other parts in my bulk collection that are basically the exact same as these. I would never have questioned that they were real LEGO before I found these.
9. They were only produced in three sets from 2006/2007: Cafe Corner (4), Piraka Stronghold (6), and The Chum Bucket (4).

Where did he get 40 of them at? Does anyone have parts like this in an official set that you KNOW are real that I can compare them to? Does anyone specifically have one of the three sets this part was found in and can help me do a comparison?

I would obviously like to sell these at some point if they were real, but don't want to sell someone fake LEGO. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hi MNAK_ and welcome to Bricks.SE! This is a wonderful first question, detailed and well-researched, way to go! Make yourself at home here, read the [help] and take the [tour] to see what our community is about and how do we operate. I'll check my parts collection if I can find this at home in the evening to see if your part is consistent with a known genuine part from the Piraka Stronghold.

Comment: [This brick on Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43888#T=C)

Answer (score 13):

I've shuffled through my pieces collection and found sadly none in dark blue, but all 17 I've found in either old grey or red have the same attributes you mention:

1. Top stud is hollow, with an H-shaped cutout
2. There is no LEGO logo or part number anywhere
3. There is a small seam that runs along the full length of the part on opposite sides
4. There is a small number (between 2 and 8) on the outside of the part on the bottom of the rounded section
5. The part feels like LEGO and has the new LEGO sheen

Single-digit number at the bottom:
[image: Single-digit number at the bottom]

H-shaped cutout in the hollow open stud:
[image: H-shaped cutout in the hollow open stud]

Seam running over the opposite sides:
[image: Seam running over the opposite sides]

I'm 100% sure these are all genuine LEGO pieces, the red ones from [7419: Dragon Fortress](https://brickset.com/sets/7419-1/Dragon-Fortress).

Comment: I appreciate the time and the pics. This looks exactly like what I have, I'm pretty sure they're real at this point. Thanks!

Comment: @MNAK_ You're welcome, but considering the answer from Joost and the comment by Alex I'm starting to get doubts about whether the mould has been updated since. I'm still sure my pieces are original, but if theirs are too, there is no net new information gained.

Comment: And, of course, this supports Lego's policy of not just throwing their old moulds in the dumpster out back.

Comment: Is there value in accurately weighing 10 pieces and providing an average weight for one?   OP might weigh theirs and find its half the weight implying fake, or similar weight implying identical.

Comment: @Criggie it could discover an inconsistency, which would strongly indicate the non-originality of the part. But if the weights are close enough, they could still be different makes (although with the number of similarities increasing the likelihood of any knock-offs among them is decreasing). See in [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/10659/3631) the paragraph starting with "And in the unthinkable case".

Answer (score 6):

My best guess, they are fake.

Mainly because of point 4 & 5

- Lego is always very keen on hiding the seam caused by the molding
- Lego include in most molds a mound number but they are always hidden out of view.
  Can you read the number?

I don't have this version of the part but the other non-hollow one in white. I checked for these two marks and couldn't find either a seam or number on them.

The cafe corner as a modular building has always been a very popular set and therefor copied by the different clone brands. You can still get 1 for 80-90 USD, which can explain why you got 40 of them.

Comment: I'e checked with elements I have and confirm that points 4 and 5 you've mentioned are valid - LEGO element doesn't have a seam at all and no numbers are visible on exterior (inside as well).

Comment: I would normally agree which is why I'm so uncertain. I've just never found fake LEGO that feels so much like the real thing, and the fact that I and others have parts in their collection that look the same leads me to believe that they're real. Thanks for taking the time to respond.